# Node.Js Express views path with sub routing

Tags: node.js, express, view, routes, path

I have a sort of this kind of folder structure for my node.js Express application:

```
/app
  /app_api
  /app_srv
    /routes
      /uri_a
        index.js
      /uri_b
        index.js
      /...
      index.js
  /uploads
  /views
  /...
  app.js
```

Abstractly

Each `/uri_x/index.js` is exported as an `express.router()` module and define the middleware to handle the http methods for that specific uri

The `/routes/index.js` is also exported as an `express.Router()` that import the routers from each `/uri_x/index.js` and set the use for that specific uri

`app.js` imports the `\routes` router and set it as the route handler for the application routes i.e. `app.use('/', app_router)`

**/routes/uri_a/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';

const appa = module.exports = express.Router();

appa.get('uri_a', (req, res, next) => {
  ...
};
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';

import appa from './a_uri';

const app_router = module.exports = express.Router();

app_router.use('/a_uri', appa);

app_router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {

  //render start page
};
```

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';

import path from 'path';

// ...

import app_router from './app_srv/routes';

// ...

/** here is where is going to be the to be or not of the question **/

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname), 'app_srv' ,'views');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// ...

app.use('/', app_routers);

// ...
```

Everything seam to work seamlessly excepto for that the `__dirname` changes for each uri_x location loosing the path for folders set in `app.js` with `app.set` as is the case for `/views` (and also `/uploads`).

I guess this happens because each uri sub folder is acting as a sub application which _dirname becomes e.g. `c:\app\app_srv\routes\uri_x`

It has took a lot of effort to get here and now, before I start changing the application folder structure, repeating the path set in each module, or change to absolute paths, while it is plausible that other solution exist which I am not being able to find;

please...

Answer (score 0):

`path.join(__dirname)` should only be executing once, upon startup. Perhaps you're referencing it elsewhere? In any case, I'd recommend using an env var for your views directory, which you could use in your code like so:

```js
const viewFilename = path.join(process.env.VIEWS_DIR, 'somefile.pug');
```

Comment: I try to avoid to hardcode paths as it isn't a good practice of course that as a last resource it would have to do it. I was going mad because as you said and I was also expecting app.set('views', ... ) should be a one time setting, nevertheless because of sub route implementation I though I was missing something.
thanks for your kind answer,

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle it happens that

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname), 'app_srv' ,'views');
```

Has a typo and should be

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_srv' ,'views'));
```